# is it possible to generate art with PHP or JS?

Tags: javascript, php

Like our avatars: is it possible to create a simple avatar that i can use as placeholder for my users?
and extending that: how far can you go with the art preferences: colors, shape etc.

Comment: Yes? Years ago [we did this here on Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/gravatars-identicons-and-you/), with Unicorn avatars. What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. PHP is a server language. JS is a client language. Art is really general.  Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to write code that does stuff. Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link only answers are frowned upon but I think I'll take the risk: There are several libraries for those so called identicons Sampson linked to. The code there is Java (or looks very similar). A pure JavaScript implementation seems to be [jdidenticon](https://github.com/dmester/jdenticon). You have more possibilities with PHP (you can use e.g.: ImageMagick and similar) but JavaScript is cheaper for your load ;-)

Comment: thanks! this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create 2D and 3D graphics with javascript and the HTML5 tag [canvas](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/HTML/Canvas.html)

```
<canvas><canvas>
```

Inside your javascript code you define what should painted inside your canvas

```js
var context = document.getElementById("canvasId").getContext("2d");

var width = 125;  // Triangle Width
var height = 105; // Triangle Height
var padding = 20;

// Draw a path
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(padding + width/2, padding);        // Top Corner
context.lineTo(padding + width, height + padding); // Bottom Right
context.lineTo(padding, height + padding);         // Bottom Left
context.closePath();

// Fill the path
context.fillStyle = "#ffc821";
context.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasId" width="165" height="145"></canvas>
```